# How to correctly incorporate wkhtmltopdf in Django Project to download PDFs?

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have a Django project that includes an HTML that I want to be downloaded as a PDF. I correctly downloaded the wkhtmltopdf executable file and also registered it in the settings.py. however, when i try to download the PDF i get this error:

```
No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it or you can pass path to it manually in method call, check README. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```

These are some code snippets:

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def download_resume(request):
    # Retrieve data from your Django models
    personal_info = personalinfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
    summaries = summary.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
    experiences = experience.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    educations = education.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    certs = certificates.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    skillset = skills.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    # Generate the PDF content using a template
    template = get_template('template0.html')
    context = {
        'personal_info': personal_info,
        'summaries': summaries,
        'experiences': experiences,
        'educations': educations,
        'certs': certs,
        'skillset': skillset
    }

    # Render the template with the context data
    html_content = template.render(context)

    # Convert HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html_content, False)

    # Create a response with the PDF content
    response = FileResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="resume.pdf"'

    return response
```

**settings.py:**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

WKHTMLTOPDF_BIN_PATH = r'C:\Users\lulu\PycharmProjects\builderproject\wkhtmltopdf\binwkhtmltopdf.exe'
```

I made sure that the wkhtmltopdf was downloaded and registered in the settings, but when I click the download button I still get the error. What could be possibly causing this error?